# Meaning of a few lines in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Could someone explain me a few lines?

1) **char* Buffer;** 
What are we doing with this? Declaring a pointer of type char? Why do we not initialize it?

2) **MyString(const char* InitialInput)**
So this contructor(method) takes some string, turns it into a constant, basically, and assigns it to an address? Why constant and why pointer? Why can't we just write **char InitialInput**?

3) **const char* InitialInput** Why is there a derefernce operator as well as constant here? As I understand this is a method? What's wrong with just writing **char GetString()**?

Changing some of these to the way I "want" results in **deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'** Not sure what this mean...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class MyString 
{
private:
    char* Buffer;

public:
    // constructor
    MyString(const char* InitialInput)
    {
        if(InitialInput != NULL)
        {
            Buffer = new char [strlen(InitialInput) + 1];
            strcpy(Buffer, InitialInput);
        }
        else
            Buffer = NULL;
    }
    // destructor 
    ~MyString()
    {
        cout << "Invoking destructor, clearing up" << endl;
        if (Buffer != NULL)
            delete[] Buffer;
    }

    int GetLength()
    {
        return strlen(Buffer);
    }

    const char* GetString()
    {
        return Buffer;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString SayHello("I am saying hello to you!");
    cout << "String buffer in MyString is " << SayHello.GetLength();
    cout << " charecters long" << endl;

    cout << "Buffer contains: " << SayHello.GetString() << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: Here, [get a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: As @Barmar suggests, get a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start with chapter one - you can't learn to program by guess-work

Comment: What basics exactly? It's from http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-Hour-Edition/dp/0672335670 and I've worked through pointers, using const with pointers, and dynamically allocating memory, and the author threw this example without explaining some stuff in a chapter on Destructors. For instance I know what * means, but it hasn't been explained why it was used in a class like this char* Buffer;... I'm pretty sure I've worked well thru the book until this chapter. I don't know maybe it's not a good book? Or maybe this wasn't yet supposed to be explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char*` is typically used to point at the first element in an array of `char`s, where one of the `char`s in the array is `\0` and denotes the end of a string. We refer to such `char*`s as *C-style strings*. That is, this type represents a *string* of characters, whereas a single `char` represents only a single character.

A `const char*` is similar (still a C-style string), but says that we do not wish to modify the `char`s that are being pointed at (we only need to look at them).

`char* Buffer;` is a member of the `MyString` class. Yes, it is not being initialised, but it is being assigned to in the constructor of the class. This occurs before any other use of the member, so it's safe.

The constructor takes a `const char*` because it needs a string of characters to fill the `Buffer` with. `GetString` returns a `const char*` because it returns the string of characters from the `Buffer`.

Comment: Hum, thanks a lot. I know about most of these facts separately, but just couldn't fit in my head. For instance I didn't know you should still write const char* for a return method, because that just seemed unnatural, since we're not declaring anything here and just returning. But I think all of this more or less makes sense now. Thanks again. Don't know why people are so mad :)

Comment: @Max `const char*` is a type. You can use it anywhere a type is expected. A return type is a type. An argument type is a type.